# C++ windows socket accept() failed with errorcode 0

Tags: sockets

I wrote a simple C/S project in VS2012..But it dont work.

The code of server:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define BU_SIZ 64

int main(){
WSADATA wd;
SOCKET s;

if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wd) != 0){
    cout<<"er stup";
    return 0;
}
cout<<"V:"<<wd.wVersion<<endl;
cout<<"H V:"<<wd.wHighVersion<<endl;
cout<<"Dsp:"<<wd.szDescription<<endl;
cout<<"Sys:"<<wd.szSystemStatus<<endl;

s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(s == INVALID_SOCKET){
    cout<<"failed in socket"<<endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

SOCKADDR_IN sa;
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_port = htons(33333);
sa.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

int ret;
ret = bind(s,(const struct sockaddr*)&sa,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
if(ret == SOCKET_ERROR){
    cout<<"failed in bind"<<endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;

}
ret = listen(s,2);
if(ret == SOCKET_ERROR){
    cout<<"failed in listen"<<endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}
cout<<"server start"<<endl;
sockaddr_in ca;
int ca_len = sizeof(ca);
SOCKET c;
c = accept(s,(sockaddr  FAR*)&ca,&ca_len);
int r = WSAGetLastError();
if(c = SOCKET_ERROR){
    cout<<"failed in accept"<<endl;
    cout<<r<<endl<<endl;
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}
char buf[BU_SIZ];
while(1){
    ZeroMemory(buf,BU_SIZ);
    ret = recv(c,buf,BU_SIZ,0);
    if(ret == SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout<<"failed in listen"<<endl;

        closesocket(s);
        closesocket(c);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    if(strcmp(buf,"quit") == 0){
        ret = send(c,"quit",sizeof("quit"),0);
        break;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"msg is:"<<buf<<endl;
    }
    closesocket(s);
    closesocket(c);
    WSACleanup();
}
return 0;
}
```

The code of client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"WS2_32.lib")

using namespace std;
#define BUF_SIZ 64
int main(){
SOCKET c;
WSADATA wd;
char buf[BUF_SIZ] = {0};
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wd);

c = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

SOCKADDR_IN ca;
ca.sin_family = AF_INET;
ca.sin_port = htons(33333);
ca.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("192.168.199.232");
int ret;
ret = connect(c,(LPSOCKADDR)&ca,sizeof(ca));
if(ret == SOCKET_ERROR){
    cout<<"fail at conn"<<endl;
    closesocket(c);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

cout<<"after conn"<<endl;
while(1){
    string st;
    cin>>st;
    int i = 0;
    do{
        buf[i] = st[i];
    }while(st[i] != 0);

    ret = send(c,buf,strlen(buf)+1,0);
    if(ret == SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout<<"fail at send"<<endl;
        closesocket(c);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    recv(c,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
    if(strcmp(buf,"quit") == 0){
        break;
    }
}
closesocket(c);
WSACleanup();




return 0;
}
```

After run ,server show[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHlKN.jpg)
Aftre client run:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg6Ws.jpg)

The client show "after conn",but it dont terminate.

Answer (score 0):

just because I lose an equal..if(==) but I write if(=)